# A small area on my Windows 7 desktop cannot be clicked

Tags: windows-7, windows

IT is a small area within the normal icons area on desktop of Windows 7 64bits version. It looks normal but when I try to click on it, it would have no response. If I move a folder on this area, then I cannot click on the folder. Even when there is nothing over there, when I click on it then it would not have any response like there should be a manual after clicking right button. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Could be spyware with some sort of ad that's not properly showing up, I'd grab combofix and see if you have any luck removing it.  It could be a program that is completely legit that you just forgot you installed or something.  If it's a new problem that happened very recently you could do a system restore to put the computer back to before it was like this.

Intro on what combofix is and how to use it/download it:
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a program which has overlaid the desktop then for some reason crashed. The simple fix is to logoff and then back on. If that fixes it but you later find it keeps coming back you'll need to actually identify what is the program causing this and quit using it or deal with it otherwise.